# Is Logros an actual thing in DC comics?

Tags: dc, comics

Spectre #37 ('92 series) mentions Logros as the "real" or "mythic" Britain. It is mentioned again in the next issue although I think the spelling gets changed to Loghros.

I can't find any reference to this via Google in DC comics or in mythology in general.

- Is Logros something they made up for Spectre #37 and then never used elsewhere?
- Is it a piece of mythology that they mangled the spelling of so badly Google can't correct it?
- Did someone typo "Logos" and it slipped past the editor because they had no idea what the writer was trying to convey anyway?
- Are there other references to Logros out there for me to find?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logres ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said it's hard to find much information as to what they meant by Logros. The closest I could find was something called Logres I found on Wikipedia. While its impossible to know for sure if this is what they were referring and they just misspelled Logres, this at least logically works.

Logres is used as the name of King Arthur's realm in a collection of medieval literature. Franklin's dialogue is extremely vague and hard to understand, but his argument is for creating a spiritual representation of America. King Arthur is a mythical (maybe based on a real king) hero of old Britain that represents ideals that at least in that time period the nation of Britain strived to be. A strong military king for Britain's super power status that also represents the ideals of justice and chivalry. In this sense, King Arthur is the spiritual representation of Britain and King Arthur's realm is known as Logres. So when Franklin talks about Logros in reference to Britain, he could be referring to King Arther, just as Britain has the spiritual realm of Logres with King Arthur to go alongside Britain so will this fledging nation have a spiritual representation to go along with the political one.

Franklin does refer to Logros (Which may be Logres) as the real nation this could be in reference to the ideals of King Arthur and his realm representing the ideas of the real nation of Britan without corruption, as Uncle Sam is meant to represent the true ideals and will of the nation even when the nation itself falters and fractures.

Its impossible to know if this is what Franklin actually meant but it makes a lot of sense if it was and its only one letter off.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logres

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Arthur

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by providing a bit more information, and providing a reliable source for your information.